# when locally running 'aws stepfunctions' how to use the statemachine ASL file for the definition

Tags: aws-step-functions, aws-sam

Is there a way in the AWS `sam` and `aws` environment to invoke a SAM step function locally, using the same json file that is defined in the SAM project?

I'm trying to locally invoke the sample step function in the AWS "Stock Trade" example, but supply the **filename** of the .asl.json file instead of manually recreating the json (to de-reference variable names) and pasting it onto the command line.

I have the two necessary docker containers running, eg

```
sam local start-lambda
```

and

```
docker run -p 8083:8083 amazon/aws-stepfunctions-local
```

are running in separate Mac terminal windows.

The step function is defined in the file `statemachine/stock_trader.asl.json`

The issue is that 100% of guides I can find simply regurgitate the same AWS example that creates the statemachine via stdin instead of a filename.

Although I could not find any documented examples, on a hunch I found that I can supply a json file by using `--definition file://PATH/FILE` for example

```
aws stepfunctions --endpoint http://localhost:8083 create-state-machine \
    --definition file://statemachine/stock_trader.asl.json \
    --name StockTradingStateMachine --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/DummyRole"
```

However, that (naturally) just inserts the literal json file... e.g., with variable names such as `"Resource": "${StockCheckerFunctionArn}"` instead of the local ARNs for the resources.

Is there any way to de-reference the variable names inside the json file? Or must we manually create (and maintain) duplicate json files with manually-replaced "local" ARNs for every referenced resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope a better solution comes along, but here's what I do currently...

I invoke the statemachine in a Bash script, which invokes sed to manually re-write the generic template into a json file with the parameters replaced from values specified in the bash script

Here's a small single-variable example:

```
$template_source=template.json 
$sm_actual=ready_to_use.json # a "runable" tmp file with placeholders replaced with actual variable names
$sm_function_tag=REPLACEMENT_TEXT
$sm_name=MyFunctionName
$sm_arn=arn:aws:states:us-east-1:MYACCOUNT:stateMachine:$sm_name

# THIS creates the de-referenced json file
# (can have 5 -e params if replacing 5 placeholders)
sed -e "s/REPLACEME/$sm_function_tag/"  ./statemachine/$template_source > ./statemachine/$sm_actual  || exit 2

# THIS copies the file into a bash variable 
json_text=$(cat ./statemachine/$sm_actual)

# This supplies the de-referenced json file contents to the `--definition` parameter:
aws stepfunctions CMD-INVOKE-UPLOAD-WHATEVER \
  --no-cli-pager \
  --state-machine-arn $sm_arn \
  --role-arn  $sm_role_arn \
  --definition "$json_text" \
  --profile AWS-PROFILE-TO-USE || exit 2
```